# Secure Connection Failed with FireFox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8, mozilla

I have created an application which has UI on js. 
It uploads huge file and then processes it. Application works fine on Google Chrome but end up with error on Firefox and IE.

Error: 
Secure Connection Failed
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Comment: Try to clear the cache and cookies for your website and try again. It can be an issue of the connection time out. So you can try to check for it. Try to make a test with small files to check whether it can be producible with the small files or not.

Comment: The issue is not with smaller files but with the larger files. My java application processes larger files. 
So it takes time in upload and processing both and hence browser end up with "Secure Connection Failed" error.
I have never encountered the issue on Google Chrome even if with the larger files.

Comment: Hi @saurabh4590 did you resolve this issue? I am having the same error in Firefox. IE is working.